# Is this logic behind the derivative of $x^x$ a coincidence?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

As many of you probably know, when you take the derivative of $x^x$, you cannot treat it as either a exponential function ($a^x$) or like a function of the form $x^a$.

If you treat it like $x^a$ then you get an aswer of $xx^{x-1}$, which is just $x^x$.

Treat it like $a^x$, and you get $x^xln(x)$.

The correct derivative is $x^x(ln(x)+1)$, which you get by doing implicit differentiation after taking the natural log of both side.

This is the same as $x^xln(x)+x^x$, which happens to be the combination of the "wrong" derivatives you get when treating $x^x$ as the 2 different types of functions I specified earlier.

Is there any real logic behind this or is it coincidence. Also, could this also be applied to other function hybrids like $x^x$?

Comment: Putting \ before common function names makes them look much nicer. Compare $ln$ with $\ln$.

Comment: Ok, thanks for heads up!

Comment: If you have JSTOR (or **Mathematics Teacher**) access, see my "Reader Reflections" note [*Derivatives of generalized power functions*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/20876724) in **Mathematics Teacher**, Volume 103, Number 9 (May 2010) pp. 630-631. Among other things, I mention that the rules for differentiating $f(x)g(x)$ (product rule), $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ (quotient rule), and ${f(x)}^{g(x)}$ follow from the rule for finding the total derivative of a function of $2$ variables, and literature references (textbooks, as well as apparent re-discoveries published in elementary teaching journals).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this is the answer you're looking for. Consider the function of two variables
$$f(x,y) = x^y = e^{y\ln x}.$$
Then
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = \left(\frac yx\right) x^y \quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}= (\ln x)x^y.$$
By the multivariable chain rule (setting $y=x$ in the second coordinate)
$$\frac d{dx} f(x,x) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big|_{(x,x)} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big|_{(x,x)}\cdot 1 = \left(\frac xx + \ln x\right)x^y = (1+\ln x)x^y.$$

Answer (score 5):

Let $F$ be a nice function of two variables, and define
$$f(x)=F(x,x).$$
By the chain rule,
$$f'(x)=F_1(x,x)+F_2(x,x)$$
where $F_1$ and $F_2$ are the partial derivatives of $F$ with respect to its
two arguments.

Here, take
$$F(x,y)=x^y.$$ Then
$$F_1(x,y)=yx^{y-1}$$
and
$$F_2(x,y)=(\ln x)x^y.$$
So
$$f'(x)=xx^{x-1}+(\ln x)x^x=(1+\ln x)x^x$$
just as you observed.

Comment: Thank you very much - I wasn't aware of the chain rule for a multivariable function

Comment: The chain rule is $$\frac d{dx}F(u(x),v(x))=u'(x)F_1(u(x),v(x))+v'(x)F_2(u(x),v(x)).$$ Here, $u(x)=v(x)=x$ which is really convenient. @JakubSkop

Answer (score -1):

Regarding "treating like $a^x$ versus $x^a$", the logic is that the $a^x$ rule applies when the base $a$ is constant, and the $x^a$ rule applies only when the exponent $a$ is constant, and so you simply do not apply those rules to $x^x$.

So what do you do? Implicit differentiation is not necessary. Instead, you should start from the very definition of exponentials:
$$y = x^x = e^{x \, \ln(x)}
$$
At this point, it becomes very clear and logical what you should do, namely apply first the chain rule then the product rule:
$$\frac{dy}{dx} = e^{x \, \ln(x)} \frac{d}{dx}(x \ \ln(x)) = e^{x \, \ln(x)} (1 \cdot \ln(x) + x \frac{1}{x}) = x^x (\ln(x) + 1)
$$

Comment: Thanks, but I wasn't asking for the derivative - I already knew that. I was just asking why the flawed method of treating it as 2 different functions and adding the derivatives also worked

Comment: That was the nature of my answer, namely, to give the actual logic which points one away from the flawed derivations, and towards a valid derivation. In general, the logic I would follow is to try to derive a new derivative formula from the old derivative formulas that you already know.

Comment: Actually, as someone pointed out, the logic was not completely flawed - just check one of the other answers.

Comment: Yes, I understand those answers. My answer is different, the addition you are curious about just comes from the product rule.